# Book about a frozen dystopian world

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

In 2009 I read a book for school, which I'd like to re-read but I cannot remember the title.
It was about a boy and a girl in some dystopian world (I think it was told from both of their perspectives and that they weren't together all the time or possibly at all). 
The world was icecold or frozen too, (they perhaps even burned things to feel warm) and I remember there was also something about a motorcycle gang (with horns on their helmets) and a king.

Comment: I find wikipedia list can be very helpful. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dystopian_literature

Comment: Is this a recent book (published around the time you read it) or an older book? Any idea how old? Is it a book for Young Adults?

Comment: I haven't found it immediately on the wiki page, though I might read a few later to know for sure.I don't know, I read it in Dutch because I was still in high school (4th grade) and I recently looked at documents from that year and it only says 'read a book for the exam' and there isn't even a booklist. So I have no idea about the publication date